# rails server wont run after removing devise 3.0.0.rc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

Ok, I've just uninstalled devise 3.0.0.rc. I don't need it anymore. I'll settle with 3.0.2. I removed it from my gem file.  But every time I want to start my rails server I get the error:

```
Could not find devise-3.0.0.rc in any of the sources
Run 'bundle install' to install missing gem.
```

Comment: im using rails 4 by the way

Comment: Have you tried `bundle install` as message tells you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run `bundle install` when you remove gems from your `Gemfile` as well as when you add them. It will rebuild the `Gemfile.lock` with the list of gems for your application. At the moment, I suspect, your Gemfile.lock still has the devise gem in it and your application is looking for that gem as a result when it starts up. `bundle install` will rebuild your `Gemfile.lock` to not include that gem.